# CSS, why is min() function in max-width not working?

Tags: html, css

In the code below, I set the `max-width` of the 1st image to be `min(40px, 10%)`, but apparently it doesn't work. Firefox says “Invalid property value”. Why is that?

```css
img#test1
{
  max-width: min(40px, 10%);
}

img#test2
{
  max-width: 10%;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <title></title>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
</head>

<body>
  <div>
    <img id="test1" src="https://i.imgur.com/JfmBtYb.png" />
  </div>
  <div>
    <img id="test2" src="https://i.imgur.com/JfmBtYb.png" />
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: `min()` is not a thing in CSS (yet). Use Sass/Less

Comment: It's at Editor's Draft stage

Comment: @MTCoster your own link says it's not in CSS, but a WIP.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your problem has to do with browser compatibility for min(). It's not yet widely adopted, even the https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/min DOC shows that compatibility is unknown for many browsers.

Comment: Ah, ok. I was looking at MDN, but failed to notice the compatibility section. I know `calc()` works, so I assumed `min()` is the same status.

Comment: I don't think showing the different possible values for max-width is relevant because min() will resolve to a length thus it's a valid value of max-width (like calc() ) ... the compatibility issue is the relevant part